# "Not found" error with resource routing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following route:

```
Route::resource('pools', 'PoolsController');
```

In the `PoolsController`, the `index` method works fine. If I open www.domain.com/pools it will run the content of `index()`.

However, I'm running into an issue with the `show()` method, specifically when trying to pass a parameter to it. I want to open www.domain.com/pools/show/12 where 12 is an ID from the database, but when I do this I get a `NotFoundHttpException`. When I open www.domain.com/pools/show (without the parameter) it runs the method correctly - but this is obviously useless without the ID of the resource to be shown.

So I'm wondering why this isn't working. From what I've found online, this should be the way to pass a parameter to a controller method.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: add your `show()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, route `www.domain.com/pools/show/12` is not defined. What you have defined in your routes is `resource('pools')`and that means you should browse to `www.domain.com/pools/12` and `12` will be passed to the `show()` method of the controller. When you open same url without parameters, `show` will be passed to `show()` method.

For further docs on RESTful resource controller visit [this link](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers)

Comment: Ah, I see. I seem to have missed this lesson when I read about resourceful routing. What confused me is that it worked without the ID, didn't realize that it thought "show" itself was the parameter.